# If $G=D_{\infty}=\lbrace x, y\vert x^{2}=y^{2}=1\rbrace$ then what is $G/\langle x\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G=D_{\infty}=\lbrace x, y\vert x^{2}=y^{2}=1\rbrace$ then what is $G/\langle x\rangle$? I thought that it'd be $\langle y\rangle$ but I've been told this is incorrect. Am I missing something obvious? And then why does $\mathbb{Z}[G/\langle x\rangle]=\mathbb{Z}[\langle y\rangle]$?

Comment: There are two things that you are missing, which if you can resolve will help you :-). Firstly, $G/\langle x\rangle$ isn't a group (why not? So what kind of structure is it?!). Secondly, $G/\langle x\rangle$ is not going to consist of elements of $x$, so it isn't going to be $\langle y\rangle$! (Working out the answer to the first point will help you with the second point.)

Comment: Okay, I'm still confused as to what $G/\langle x\rangle$ looks like. I thought it would be $\lbrace 1, y\rbrace$...or is it all the elements that aren't actually in $\langle x\rangle$?

Comment: The key word is "coset". (Also, $G/\langle x\rangle$ is an infinite set. You are assuming that $\langle x\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which it isn't)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[G/\langle x \rangle]$ does not make sense. Are you sure that the question was not about $G/\langle xy \rangle$?

Comment: I meant by $\mathbb{Z}[G/\langle x\rangle]$ the free abelian group with basis the set $G/\langle x\rangle$

Comment: The answer is then easy - these two free abelian groups are isomorphic (not *equal* though!) as both of the sets $\langle y\rangle$ and $G/\langle x\rangle$ are countably infinite (why?), and then apply uniqueness of the free abelian group on a countably infinite set.

Comment: I don't see how $\langle x\rangle$ is countably infinite doesn't it just contain $1$ and $y$??

Comment: Sorry I meant $\langle y\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^{-1}=x$, and same for $y$. Therefore, if you conjugate $x$ by $y$ you get
$$x^y = yxy \not \in \langle x \rangle$$ which means that $\langle x \rangle$ is not a normal subgroup. Also note that $X= \langle x \rangle = \{1, x\}$.

In particular, this means that the quotient will not necessarily inherit the group structure from $G$, and in this particular case it indeed doesn't. By definition of quotient between groups:
$$G/X = \{aX, a \in G\}$$

the set of *cosets*, where $aX = \{ax, x \in X\}$ so in our case just $\{a, ax\}$. In particular, note that $yX \neq yxyX$ since $yxy \neq y$ and $yxy \neq yx$, so it cannot be $\langle y \rangle$ as there are at least three elements/cosets $(1, y, yxy)$.

In fact, as sets $G/X = G_y$ if we denote by $G_y$ the set of elements of $G$ that "end with $y$" (you can "remove" any $x$ at the end of an element $a \in G$ as $ax$ and $a$ are in the same cosets, so the last digit has to be $y$ because $x^2=1$) plus the identity coset or, equivalently, $G/X = G_x$ with similar reasoning.

Be careful though, as this does *not* inherit the group structure from $G$.

I agree with another comment above: I do not understand your second question.

Comment: Ahh yes! That makes total sense! In my second question I meant by $\mathbb{Z}[G/\langle x\rangle]$ the free abelian group with basis the set $G/\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: user1729 gave an excellent answer in the comments above then